# custom error message for empty username and password using authenticate filter not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to override the [authenticate](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/) to edit the default error message.

```
/**
Purposed: Custom Login Error Message
Description: This function override the default error message on login form.
**/
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password' );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_username_password', 30, 3 );
/**
 * Remove Wordpress filer and write our own with changed error text.
 */
function custom_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') )
        return $user;

    if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) ) {
        if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
            return $user;
        
        $error = new WP_Error();
        if ( empty( $username ) )
            $error->add('empty_email', __('The username or email field is empty.'));

        if ( empty( $password ) )
            $error->add('empty_password', __( 'The password field is empty' ));

        return $error;
    }

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

    if ( !$user )
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', sprintf( __( 'Invalid username or email address.' ), wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    $user = apply_filters( 'wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        return $user;

    if ( ! wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) )
        return new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password', sprintf( __( 'The password you\'ve entered is incorrect.' ),
        $username, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    return $user;
}
```

Unfortunately, the empty username or password error is not overriding.

The default error message for username and password are;
`<strong>Error</strong> : The username field is empty.`
`<strong>Error</strong> : The password field is empty.`

I would like to change it to;
`The username or email field is empty.`
`The password field is empty.`

However, the `invalid_username` and `incorrect_password` are working and I successfully override it.

Comment: Im no expert but just thinking out loud... If you can do a `global $errors` (note the 's' at the end), that should give you all the array data from the core $errors variable. Find the one that the core generates for the username, and replace your `invalid_username' with what they provide?

Answer (score 0):

You have an or statement and an individual statement, it's only going to return one. Try changing it around a little:

**Updated**

Regardless of how you would like to structure your code, I added the `$error->get_error_messages();` at the end of the error. For more more information, you can have a look at this information: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress-error-handling-with-wp_error-class-i--cms-21120

```
    if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) ) {
        
        $error = new WP_Error();
        
        if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) ) {
            if ( empty( $username ) ) {
                $error->add( 'empty_email', __( 'The username or email field is empty.' ) );
            }
            if (empty( $password ) ) {
                $error->add( 'empty_password', __( 'The password field is empty' ) );
            }
        }
        
        return $error->get_error_messages();
    
    } elseif ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            
        return $user->get_error_message();
         
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Adding braces to conditions won't make any changes. As you know, when you omit the braces it will only treat the next statement as a body of the condition.

Comment: I write with braces, you can write how you like, but it's the elseif that I thought might help the other errors show if they are activated.

Comment: Updated my answer. This is what I have done in my own validations, and it returns codes.

Comment: will produce of 
**Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home3/tesoli/public_html/web/wp-includes/user.php on line 101**

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the reason why it doesn't overriding.

```
if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) ) {
        if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
            return $user;
        ...
```

Try to remove this condition.

```
if (is_wp_error( $user ) )
  return $user;
```

It should be something like this.

```
/**
Purposed: Custom Login Error Message
Description: This function override the default error message on login form.
**/
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password' );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_username_password', 30, 3 );
/**
 * Remove Wordpress filer and write our own with changed error text.
 */
function custom_authenticate_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if (is_a($user, 'WP_User')){
        return $user;
    }
    
    if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        $error = new WP_Error();
        if (empty($username )){
            $error->add('empty_email', __('The username or email field is empty.'));
        }

        if (empty($password)){
            $error->add('empty_password', __( 'The password field is empty' ));
        }
        return $error;
    }

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    if (!$user){
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', sprintf( __( 'Invalid username or email address.' ), wp_lostpassword_url()));
    }
    $user = apply_filters( 'wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password );
    if (is_wp_error($user)){
        return $user;
    }
    if (!wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID )){
        return new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password', sprintf( __( 'The password you\'ve entered is incorrect.' ),
        $username, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );
    }
    return $user;
}
```

Notice that I added braces to every condition to make it more clear.

You might also want to override the function `wp_authenticate_email_password`.

```
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_email_password' );
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_authenticate_email_password', 31, 3 );
function custom_authenticate_email_password( $user, $email, $password ) {
    if ($user instanceof WP_User) {
        return $user;
    }

    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $error = new WP_Error();
        if ( empty( $email ) ) {
            // Uses 'empty_username' for back-compat with wp_signon().
            $error->add( 'empty_username', __( 'The username or email field is empty.' ) );
        }
        if ( empty( $password ) ) {
            $error->add( 'empty_password', __( 'The password field is empty.' ) );
        }
        return $error;
    }

    if (!is_email($email)) {
        return $user;
    }

    $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
    if (!$user) {
        return new WP_Error('invalid_email',__( 'Invalid username or email address.' ));
    }

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/user.php */
    $user = apply_filters( 'wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password );
    if (is_wp_error($user)){
        return $user;
    }

    if (!wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID)){
        return new WP_Error('incorrect_password',sprintf( __( 'The password you\'ve entered is incorrect.' ),
        $email, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );
    }

    return $user;
}
```

There are two functions under `authenticate`, `wp_authenticate_username_password` and `wp_authenticate_email_password`. Try to override both of them, maybe one of them has the error message that is not overriding, use the codes above and examine.

Comment: It does fix the issue. However, from the original file located on `wp_includes` > `user.php` the condition is present. Why is that, using it on the filter doesn't work and why removing it is working?

Comment: Anyway, thanks for `wp_authenticate_email_password` I didn't know its a thing